# Como pegar o valor default de um tipo em Kotlin?

Tags: característica-linguagem, kotlin

Estou vindo do C# e começando a trabalhar com Kotlin (Android). Em C#, caso eu queira o valor esperado padrão para um tipo eu devo chamá-lo como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Foo {}

class Main 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var d_string   = default(string)   // = null
        var d_int      = default(int)      // = 0
        var d_bool     = default(bool)     // = false
        var d_DateTime = default(DateTime) // = 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
        var d_Foo      = default(Foo)      // = null
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se existe qualquer forma de retornar o valor padrão de uma tipo como no exemplo acima em Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin não tem nada parecido, e a saída é usar o literal

Normalmente é um valor 0, algum tipo de 0, não necessariamente 0.

Isto significa que suas suposições em C# para `string` e `Foo` estão erradas. Por ser tipos por referência, por isso seu valor é um ponteiro, o 0 delas é um valor nulo, e não um texto vazio, muito menos é o tipo `object`. Já `0`, `false` e um horário inicial do calendário que não é bem é um zero interno ainda que a representação textual mostre como dia 1 do mês 1 e ano 1 são valores que podem ser considerados 0. Tem uma [tabela](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table) deles.

Vou deixar aqui este texto porque este usuário tem a mania de fazer a pergunta errada e depois consertar, aí parece que a resposta fala de coisas que não existe na pergunta.

Em Kotlin deve ser todos valores iguais, mas seria bom confirmar. Se não for vou começar achar Kotlin esquisita, ainda mais que em Java é igual ao C#.

Na grande maioria dos casos faz mais sentido usar um `default(T)` ou alguma forma assim porque não sabe que tipo é, mesmo em C# quando sabe o tipo faz pouco sentido usar esta forma e não o literal. Até pode ser em algum caso onde quer facilitar uma mudança ou quer garantir que algo não compila se usar um valor impróprio para aquele tipo, o que é raro ser um problema real. Também é possível usar o `default` sozinho quando o compilador pode inferir o tipo, aí faz um pouco mais de sentido, mas muito pouco, eu prefiro usar o literal.

Então vai sem medo no literal do tipo mesmo, principalmente porque nem tem uma justificativa na pergunta para usar diferente.

Comment: Eu compreendo que os códigos acima estavam errados tanto que até corrigi os mesmos, a questão é que estava buscando o recurso  `default(T)` dentro do Kotlin.